# Livepatch not working in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: canonical-livepatch

sudo ua enable livepatch gets the following answer

```
One moment, checking your subscription first
Stderr: internal error, please report: running "canonical-livepatch" failed: cannot find installed snap "canonical-livepatch" at revision 132: missing file /snap/canonical-livepatch/132/meta/snap.yaml
Stdout: 
Unable to configure Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch config remote-server=https://livepatch.canonical.com' [exit(46)]. Message: internal error, please report: running "canonical-livepatch" failed: cannot find installed snap "canonical-livepatch" at revision 132: missing file /snap/canonical-livepatch/132/meta/snap.yaml

ERROR: Unable to configure Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch config remote-server=https://livepatch.canonical.com' [exit(46)]. Message: internal error, please report: running "canonical-livepatch" failed: cannot find installed snap "canonical-livepatch" at revision 132: missing file /snap/canonical-livepatch/132/meta/snap.yaml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the snap installed? If not, follow this:

https://snapcraft.io/install/canonical-livepatch/ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
```